# Angular close generic Dialog testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm having Dialog Service for open, confirm and close the dialog and I am making its unit test file but I got an error wail testing the bellow method on Angular and this is the code.

**dialog.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DialogService {
  public genericDialogRef?: MatDialogRef<GenericDialogComponent>;

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) { }

  public openGenericDialog(options: GenericDialogOptions) {
const filledInConfig: Required<GenericDialogOptions> = { ...defaultValues, ...options };
this.genericDialogRef = this.dialog.open(GenericDialogComponent, {
  data: filledInConfig
});
  }

  public genericDialogClosed(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (!this.genericDialogRef)
      throw Error("Dialog ref wasn't initialized! Call open first");

    return this.genericDialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(take(1));
  }
}
```

**dialog.service.spec.ts**

```html
describe('DialogService', () => {
  let service: DialogService;
  let matDialogMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['open']);
  let toastrServiceMock = {};
  let dialog: any;
  let translateService: TranslateService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: matDialogMock },
        { provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastrServiceMock },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(DialogService);
    dialog = TestBed.inject(MatDialog);
    translateService = TestBed.inject(TranslateService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should close generic Dialog', fakeAsync(() => {

    service.genericDialogClosed().subscribe(() => {
      expect(service.genericDialogRef?.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    tick();
  }));

});
```

**Here is the error:**
[image]
could you please help me to fix this issue?

**Edit:** The below test works fine:

```html
  it('should close generic Dialog', () => {
    service.genericDialogRef = {
      afterClosed: () => of(true)
    } as MatDialogRef<GenericDialogComponent>;

    service.genericDialogClosed()
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct outcome because `genericDialogRef` was never set. Quick fix would be to set it manually, best with some mock. But since you are testing if `afterClosed` was called, you should wrap it to a `fakeAsync` function and subscribe to `genericDialogClosed` function, otherwise it won't work.

**EDIT**: As I said, I was hoping for a very simple solution, but in your case it's getting complicated. The reason is, that you assign DialogRef with a specific type to a service's property and the type check won't allow my simple value assign. So you can either mock it:

```typescript
// Create a mock
const matDialogRefMock: MatDialogRef<GenericDialogComponent> {
  // completely mock the DailogRef
  afterClosed: () => of(true);
}

it('should close generic Dialog', fakeAsync(() => {
  // then assign it before you try to close the dialog
  service.genericDialogRef = matDialogRefMock;

  service.genericDialogClosed().subscribe(() => {
    expect(service.genericDialogRef?.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  // Make the async tick happen
  tick();  
}));
```

Or you can try to open the dialog before closing it, so that the reference is existing.

```typescript
it('should close generic Dialog', fakeAsync(() => {
  // open the dialog in order to create a reference to it
  service.openGenericDialog();

  service.genericDialogClosed().subscribe(() => {
    expect(service.genericDialogRef?.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  // Make the async tick happen
  tick();  
}));
```

I had a similar test case once and when I opened the dialog in one `it` test case I assigned the reference to the top level variable, which was then available for another `it` test to close it.

Comment: I have got this error:
`TS2740: Type '{ afterClosed: () => Observable ; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MatDialogRef ': _overlayRef, _containerInstance, id, componentInstance, and 19 more.`

Comment: Yep, that's expected. I was hoping for a simplest solution, but it needs a proper mock, I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm still having the same issue mentioned in my post, Could you check my updated code again:

Comment: Try providing MatDialog as is, not its mock: ``providers: [ MatDialog, ... ]``

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: `it('should close generic Dialog', () => {
    service.genericDialogRef = {
      afterClosed: () => of(true)
    } as MatDialogRef<GenericDialogComponent>;
    service.genericDialogClosed()
  });`
this worked fine but throw Error code doesn't cover it.

Comment: What do you mean it does not cover it?

Comment: it doesn't test it